# Deploying Python model on Elastic Beanstalk AWS not working

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi I am trying to upload a model I created on Elastic Beanstalk But I am receiving the following errors:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..

Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
 
During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure 
all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
```

This is a flask application and I am not sure why it is not working. When I upload the application I upload the python file as well as the requirements.txt file all in a zip file. Any help would be appreciated.